# XSL:fo capsules table rows and cells

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

Hey guys is there a way in XSL:FO to capsule the rows and cells of a table or must capsule tables into tables to get a solution.
Here is a picture how the table should look like:
[image]

Comment: You can certainly set individual borders like border-left and border-top

Comment: nice it works but one Question if i want to indent my text i Use start-ident='2mm' It only works for the first block (in the block into block statements its always the same

Comment: Use either margins or padding on cells or the blocks in the cells.

Comment: I posted answer below for you including margin/padding showing how to indent contents

Comment: With the padding it works good for the design but if i want to insert text the rows must be the same ; I need the same row level :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly set individual borders like border-left and border-top. To indent text content as requested you can set padding on cell for entire content or margin on block inside the cell.

```
            <fo:table width="100%">
            <fo:table-column column-width="33%"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="33%"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="33%"/>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell padding-left="1in" border-left="1px solid red">
                        <fo:block>padding on cell</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border-left="1px solid red">
                        <fo:block margin-left="1in">margin on block</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border-left="1px solid red">
                        <fo:block>No padding</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
```

NOTE: Your results will depend on the renderer you are using. Apache incorrectly renders this overlapping the text in the last cells, other formatters do not. You would need to play with it to ensure you are OK with FOP.